# Get value of certain part of string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a method to get part of the string

exemple:

```
const stringModel = "game=:game, engine=:engine, version=:version"
```

I want to get the value of `:version` and `:game`

Thanks

Comment: The method you are looking for is `RegExp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions or split the string:

**Regular Expressions:**

[Here](https://regexr.com/) you can play around and test regular expressions.

```js
const stringModel = "game=:game, engine=:engine, version=:version";

// If this is not a function it will remember the index because of the g flag and not work correctly
const argRegex = () => /([^, ]+)=([^, ]+),?\s*/g;

const matches = stringModel.match(argRegex());

if (matches != null) {
   const args = matches
    .map((s) => argRegex().exec(s))
    .filter((m) => m) // Remove all null values which couldn't be matched
    .map((m) => ({ name: m[1], value: m[2] }));

  console.log(args);
}
```

**Splitting:**

```js
const stringModel = "game=:game, engine=:engine, version=:version"

const parameters = stringModel
   .split(',')
   .map((s) => s.trim().split('='));

// parameters = [ ['game', ':game'], ['engine', ':engine'], ['version', ':version'] ]

const args= parameters.map((p) => ({ name: p[0], value: p[1]}));
console.log(args);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and some string splitting

```js
const stringModel = "game=:game, engine=:engine, version=:version";

const params = Object.fromEntries(stringModel.split(',').map(s => s.trim().split('=')))

console.log(params.game)
console.log(params.version)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is nodejs library for parsing config strings

`npm i config-ini-parser`

```
var ConfigIniParser = require("config-ini-parser").ConfigIniParser;
const stringModel = "game=:game, engine=:engine, version=:version"
parser = new ConfigIniParser(',');
parser.parse(stringModel);
value = parser.get(null, "game");
console.log(value)
```